# How to fix the this on npm install: (npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies )?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, ionic-framework, npm, npm-install

Hello i have a problem  on the installation of npm:
I try to remove and reinstall but doesn't work, even removing all folders.

```
> lucas@lucas:~$ npm install
> npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies
> npm ERR! Linux 4.2.0-35-generic
> npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
> npm ERR! node v4.4.2
> npm ERR! npm  v2.15.0
> npm ERR! file /home/lucas/package.json
> npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE

> npm ERR! Failed to parse json
> npm ERR! Unexpected token ':' at 1:17
> npm ERR!   "dependencies": {
> npm ERR!                 ^
> npm ERR! File: /home/lucas/package.json
> npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
> npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
> npm ERR! 
> npm ERR! This is not a bug in npm.
> npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse

> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
> npm ERR!     /home/lucas/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: It seems your package.json file is not valid JSON. Can you provide the full file ?

Answer (score 0):

NPM's telling you what's up:

```
> npm ERR! File: /home/lucas/package.json
> npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
> npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
> npm ERR! 
> npm ERR! This is not a bug in npm.
> npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse
```

Make sure your JSON file is valid.  You can check it [on JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com).  Here's how the dependencies section should look.  Notice the surrounding object brackets.

```
{ "dependencies" :
  { "foo" : "1.0.0 - 2.9999.9999"
  , "bar" : ">=1.0.2 <2.1.2"
  , "baz" : ">1.0.2 <=2.3.4"
  , "boo" : "2.0.1"
  , "qux" : "<1.0.0 || >=2.3.1 <2.4.5 || >=2.5.2 <3.0.0"
  , "asd" : "http://asdf.com/asdf.tar.gz"
  , "til" : "~1.2"
  , "elf" : "~1.2.3"
  , "two" : "2.x"
  , "thr" : "3.3.x"
  , "lat" : "latest"
  , "dyl" : "file:../dyl"
  }
}
```

[See this writeup](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#dependencies) about the "dependencies" section of NPM's documentation, and make sure your section of `package.json` looks similar, particularly any characters coming before "dependencies".